# How I can compare and move data from A to B in Powershell older than x Days?

Tags: powershell, copy, compare, move

I have a Problem with my Powershell Script. ;( 
I want to **delete/ move/ compare** with Powershell.

**Here my Idea:**

If I start the Script I remove all empty folder from A. After that I want Move all Data from A to B that x Days older. (Here is my first problem)

If I make copy it works fine.

A other Idea is to compare A and B and only the diffrend to copy or move. (But I don't know how I can do this)

**Here is my Code:**

```
function removeFiles($source,$destination){
    $elements = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse
    foreach($element in $elements){
        if(($element.PSIsContainer) -and (!(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $element.FullName))){
            Write-Host "DELETE: " $element.FullName
            Remove-Item $element.FullName -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}

function copyFiles($source,$destination,$days){
    $elements = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse
    $lastwrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
    foreach($element in $elements){
        if($element.creationTime -le $lastwrite){
            $targetFile = $destination + $element.FullName.SubString($source.Length)
            if($element.PSIsContainer){
                Write-Host "COPY FOLDER : " $element.FullName
                Copy-Item $element.FullName -Destination $targetFile
            }else{
                Write-Host "COPY FILE : " $element.FullName
                Copy-Item $element.FullName -Destination $targetFile
            }
        }
    }
}

function moveFiles($source,$destination,$days){
   Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-2)} | Move-Item -Destination $destination
}

CLS

$Source = "C:\Users\tarasov_w\Downloads"
$Destination = "C:\Users\tarasov_w\Desktop\ps_test"
$LogFile = "C:\Users\tarasov_w\Desktop\$(get-date -format 'MMddyyyy').txt" 
$Days = 1

Start-Transcript $LogFile -noclobber

Write-Host "Start..."

removeFiles -source $Source -destination $Destination

#copyFiles -source $Source -destination $Destination -days $Days

moveFiles -source $Source -destination $Destination -days $Days

Write-Host "Fertig!"
```

**UPDATE:**

```
function compareFiles($source,$destination){
    $folderA = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse
    $folderB = Get-ChildItem $destination -Recurse

    $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folderA -DifferenceObject $folderB -PassThru

    foreach($element in $diff){
        $element_fullname = $element.FullName 

        if($element.PSIsContainer){
           # ????
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error with above script?

Comment: no it works but the script move th folder and try to move the underfolder -> error. So I have remove the -recursive by move function and it works. It is not the best solution ...better if I have a compare function that compare A and B and move only data that not exist in B. Can I do this? ... but not with robocopy^^

Comment: look on my update...how i can use move now :(